# How can I invest $3000/month to gain financial independence in 15 years, with current living expenses at $1300/month?

Tags: investing

Like the title says. My wife and I save 3100 dollars monthly. What are your suggestions on investing to reach financial independence in max 15 years? Our living costs are around 1300 dollars a month.

Comment: There are many past answers discussing basic good strategies for starting investing. This seems to be a duplicate of those. What do you want to know that we haven't addressed?

Comment: Just like hearing options for my situation

Comment: You've got 'em. We're unlikely to say anything new at this point. VTC dupe.

Comment: If you "just like hearing opinions" then this is unfortunately not a good fit for our format. We prefer questions that can be answered objectively, as opposed to ones that focus purely on peoples' opinions about a subject. Compare [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in our site's [help].

Answer (score 0):

Sounds doable.

Just put into a 2030 Target Date fund of your choice.

If you put $3100 per month for 15 years, assume a very conservative 5% return, you should get $830,000 at the end.

Imagine that your living cost increases with target inflation of 2%, $1300 x 1.02 x 1.02 ... x 1.02 (15 times) = $1750 per month.

Assume conservative Safe Withdrawal Rate of 3%.

$830,000 x 0.03 / 12 = $2075 > $1750.

Comment: We generally try to avoid recommending specific funds here, since there are almost always many that are comparable and "best" depends on the individual's timeframe and risk tolerance. If you have any affiliation with Vanguard beyond customer, please disclose it.

Comment: Even if only affiliated as a customer, it might be a good idea to state so explicitly. Lots of investment houses have target-date retirement funds, though; I think this would be equally valid without mentioning any specific name at all.